# How can i get parameter value form url with angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to get token value from url param **http://localhost:8080/security/login/#access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**
I have tried many options inside OnInit method but i get null values

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  const acessToken = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['#access_token'];
  console.error('acessToken = ' , acessToken);

  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  const token = params['#access_token'];
  console.error(' token = ' , token);
  });


  console.error('this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("#access_token") = ' , 
  this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("#access_token"));

  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.error(' params.get("access_token") = ' ,  params.get("#access_token"));
  })

  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
  console.error(' queryParams.get("#access_token") = ' , queryParams.get("#access_token"));
  })
```

Same result if i replace param name **#access_token** with **access_token** 
 Here a print screen of my console 
 [image]

Comment: Its null because your URL does not contain any query params. Generally, query params structure looks like `some-url/endpoint?param1=value1&param2&value2&...`

Comment: @MarekW  so how to get this param value ?